Lattice MachXO3 FPGA VIL and VIH of Mixed Voltage I/Os
The Lattice FPGA MachXO3 sysIO User Guide, page 12, under section "7. VCCIO Requirement for I/O Standards":



it mentions that an:

input buffer set up to be a 1.2 V ratioed input can be used on bank set to any VCCIO.

Note 10 of the same page:

This input standard can be supported using the ratioed input buffer in under-drive conditions or using the I/O types LVCMOS12R25 or LVCMOS12R33 with the referenced input buffer.

Table 3.11 "sysI/O Single-Ended DC Electrical Characteristics", page 49, in the Lattice FPGA MachXO3 Family Data Sheet, says the VIL Max for LVCMOS 1.2 is (0.35 x VCCIO) and the VIH Min is (0.65 x VCCIO)



If I want to use a 1.2V input with a 3.3V VCCIO, how can I calculate the actual VIL Max and VIH Min relating to the 1.2V input?


Did you read Note #10?

user373900 - Hi, I moved the links you kindly added, to where the copied material actually is, rather than a block of unnamed links at the end of the text. I also moved the images so that they appear in the text next to where you mention their contents - all aimed to help readability & flow. || The one part I couldn't improve is that you included table 3.10 from the family data sheet, but with no explanation of why you included it, or why specifically you want readers to notice something there. Can you please review my edit for any inadvertent errors & add an explanation for that table? TY


If I want to use a 1.2V input with a 3.3V VCCIO, how can I calculate the actual VIL Max and VIH Min relating to the 1.2V input?

As per the Note 10 in the question, a LVCMOS 1.2 V input standard with a 3.3 V VCCIO can be achieved by either:

A ratioed input buffer in under-drive conditions
Using the I/O type or LVCMOS12R33 with the referenced input buffer. Using this option requires using an external VREF pin for each I/O bank.

Determining VIL / VIH using ratioed input buffer
Looking at the Lattice documentation I can't seem to determine how to calculate VIL / VIH when using the ratioed input buffer option.
I'm not a user of Lattice MachXO3 devices, but perhaps the Diamond software would give more information about the VIL / VIH thresholds when the ratioed input buffer option is selected.
Determining VIL / VIH using referenced input buffer
Table 10.1. Supported I/O Types in the sysIO User Guide has the following entry:



sysI/O Signaling Standard
IO_TYPE




LVCMOS 1.2 V in 3.3 V VCCIO bank4
LVCMOS12R33



Where note 4 is:

These are input or bidirectional only and require VREF to be set to certain value to allow the specified I/O types to be used.

Section 10. Software sysI/O Attributes in the sysIO User Guide describes how to set the IO_TYPE and BANK VCCIO attributes in the Lattice development software to control the functions and capabilities of the sysI/O buffers.
Table 3.11. sysI/O Single-Ended DC Electrical Charateristics in the Lattice FPGA MachXO3 Family Data Sheet has the following part for the LVCMOS12R33 standard:



Standard
VIL Min. (V)
VIL Max. (V)
VIH Min. (V)
VIH Max. (V)




LVCMOS12R33
–0.3
VREF – 0.1
VREF+0.1
3.6



I.e. the VIL / VIH depends upon the VREF voltage, which as per the above is set on an external pin.
Table 3.10. sysI/O Recommended Operating Conditions in the datasheet has the following for the allowed VREF range for the LVCMOS12R33 standard:

So, if the external VREF is set to 0.6 V then:

VIL Max would be 0.5 V
HIL Min would be 0.7 V

The actual VIL / VIH thresholds will depend upon the external VREF voltage.
